# Exibir número da página corrente num dbChart

Tags: delphi

Tenho um `dbChart` exibindo os dados em múltiplas páginas. Num gráfico específico, por exemplo, há trinta pontos a serem exibidos, mas na propriedade `MaxPointsPerPage` setei apenas 10 (dez) pontos por página.
Criei botões de navegação entre as páginas para o usuário, mas o que quero, é exibir para o usuário em que página ele está.
Por exemplo, **Página 3 de 10**.
Consigo fazer isso manualmente (*via programação*).
Minhas dúvidas são:

- É possível fazer o solicitado acima nativamente no `dbChart`?
- Se sim, como?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não.

E usando as propriedades nativas do `TDBChart` você consegue usando:

```
Label1.Caption := 'Pág. '+ IntToStr(DbChart1.Page)+ ' de ' + IntToStr(DbChart1.NumPages);
```

Você pode usar o `OnPageChange` para atualizar quem vai receber esse valor!
Caso seja adicionado uma nova página ele automaticamente irá atualizar o receptor!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, certamente será útil. Mas quanto a sua edição na minha pergunta, achei totalmente desnecessária. Estava num bom português, pelo que vi com apenas um erro gramatical. E a pergunta estava clara. Se eu editar cada pergunta que estiver com um fraseado diferente do que eu desejo... vou editar todas as perguntas do _Stack_.

Comment: E apesar da resposta ser válida.. não responde o que perguntei. Pois como mencionei, _via programação_ eu consigo mostrar as páginas. O que queria era ver se tem como fazer isso nativamente (_só com uma propriedade do `dbchart`, por exemplo_).

Comment: @Andrey, Sobre a edição, é exatamente isso amigo, é normal as perguntas/respostas serem editadas para um melhor entendimento (não para deixa-la bonita), você esta usando usa `Tag` `char` que não tem nada haver com sua pergunta, por isto a edição, mas tudo Bem! Quanto a resposta, postei o código porque você cita que consegue mas não posta o que conseguiu, mas tudo Bem! Vou editar minha resposta!

Comment: E ainda sobre EDITAR Perguntas/Respostas existem recompensas por estes atos, e mais, Bem Vindo (considerando os 4 meses).

Comment: Então @Júnior Moreira como citei, sou grato a sua resposta. Quanto a `Tag` `Chart` realmente não tinha visto essa edição de sua parte (considero **válida**). Mas quanto a editar perguntas já claras para ganhar recompensa, não acho certo. De qualquer forma, pode ser que ainda falta conhecimento do _Stack_ de minha parte. Obrigado pelas dicas.